# Generalizing the ptwise or $L^1$ ergodic theorem

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, harmonic-analysis, ergodic-theory

I was able to write a proof based on the hardy-littlewood maximal function of the following statement:

Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, and $d=n \geq 1$ be fixed.  Let $\{\theta_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{Z}^d}$ be a group of measure preserving bijections.  Then if $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable integrable ($\mu$) then we have

$(2k+1)^{-n}\sum_{t \in [-k, k]^n}f \circ \theta_t$ converges a.s. as $k \rightarrow \infty$ and in $L^1$ if $\mu$ is finite and $f$ is bounded.

Notice that I can only approximate over n-dimensional discrete cubes centered at the origin.  But that's all I could possibly hope for directly from Hardy-Littlewood arguments, because that maximal function is at first defined on Euclidean balls.  You require a weak-1,1 type estimate, and you can only get that if the shapes you choose are comparable in some nice sense, where for instance, cubes, rectangles with a fixed aspect ratio, or discrete cubes, discrete rectangles all satisfy this. ("Discrete" means finite sets, and all the lebesgue measures appearing in Hardy-Littlewood turn into cardinalities of finite subsets of the integer lattice.)

But I write this question in hopes that someone will tell me how to append additional arguments to go from here to two generalizations.

1. What if I want to be able to take the limit in the strongest sense?  I.e. I don't restrict to cubes, or rectangles with a fixed aspect ratio.  Instead I want convergence as arbitrary rectangles approach the point at infinity in $\mathbb{Z}^d$  We already know that the ergodic theorem stated above would also hold if I replaced the limit over cubes with an iterated limit, one variable at a time. (By the Birkhoff ptwise ergodic theorem)  But even these two combined is not obviously sufficient for this strong limit.
2. What if I want to take averages over $[0, k]^n$ instead of symmetric about the origin?  This is clearly stronger than what I know.  Is it equivalent?

Dunford and Schwartz make the strongest claim in the sense of both 1 and 2 at the same time.  But I found at least a gap in their proof, if not a mistake.  However, [this link](http://books.google.com/books?id=OAUyQph3oVYC&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=multiparameter%20ergodic%20theorem&source=bl&ots=JghhiP2G94&sig=RBiOa2wxKzGYxEqbWdQX8JSlMAI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nF5vUqD6MIWbiQKB5IDgBQ&ved=0CFEQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=multiparameter%20ergodic%20theorem&f=false)  seems to say that the reason I found a gap is because the claim would be false, and even false if I wanted to require merely 1.  Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: I doubt I can help, but perhaps you can clarify what you mean by "converges as arbitrary rectangles approach the point at infinity in $\mathbb{Z}^d$". Also, in exactly what sense are you using the phrase "strong limit"? It sounds like you're trying to generalize the points over which you're averaging (?), but I don't know why that type of limit would be "stronger". But I'm no expert in this area!

Comment: The point at infinity is a construction called the one-point compactification.  In this case, it means that for each r>0 there exists a compact set in Z^d (namely a finite one) outside of which every point and rectangle spanned by that point centered at the origin has average within r of the supposedly existent limiting value.  That is stronger than anything else I asserted convergencewise.